# echo result from function from table in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so i am learning to write functions. Now i know how to echo stuff into a foreach but i do not know how to print a single row outside a foreach (like i only have 1 row in my table and want to print the id and username out of it) how do i do this? 
my function :

```
public function gegevens(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gegevens_locatie");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    //Return result
    return $result;
}
```

when i call that function on my other page i call it with :

```
require_once 'class/class.overig.php';
$overig = new OVERIG();
```

i have tried stuff like `print_r($overig->gevens())` and with a echo but i cant seem to make it work. So how can i do this?

Comment: what does it mean, "i cant seem to make it work"? what output you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you are using `->fetchAll()` you will always get an array of rows even if there is only one row returned. You also need to use the correct method name on your call.

So all you need to do is

```
$arr = $overig->gegevens();

if ( count($arr) == 1 ) {
    echo $arr[0]['id'];
    echo $arr[0]['username'];
}

if ( count($arr) > 1 ) {
    foreach ( $arr as $row) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['username'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"I have tried stuff like `print_r($overig->gevens())` and with a echo but i cant seem to make it work. So how can i do this?"*

The Name of the Method you called does NOT match the Name of the Method in your Class. In your Class, You have: `gegevens()` but in your Call: you specified: `gevens()`. Unless this is just a normal Typo; you should start your Debugging from there.

In other words; your Call should have been: `print_r($overig->gegevens())`.

> **THE CLASS:**

```
    <?php

        class OVERIG{
            public function gegevens(){
                $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM gegevens_locatie");
                $stmt->execute();

                $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

                //Return result
                return $result;
            }
        }
```

> **USING THE CLASS:**

```
    <?php

        require_once 'class/class.overig.php';
        $overig = new OVERIG();
        $result = $overig->gegevens();

        // TRY DUMPING THE VARIABLE: $result:
        var_dump($result);


        // TO ECHO OUT SOME VALUES:
        if($result){
            foreach($result as $key=>$item){
                if(is_string($item)){
                    echo $item;
                }
            }
        }
```